# Preventing "$_" from being omitted from variable content

Tags: powershell, replace, escaping

I am reading a large blob of text that I regex out of another like so

```
$myVar = Select-String -Pattern '(?<=search\s=\s).*[\s*](?s).*' -input $myContent -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches}
```

The regex works well. The content of `$myVar` is code (can be powershell too), so it can contain special characters. As a result of this, `$myVar` sometimes contains the character "`$_`", which is also the $PSItem in Powershell. When I try to process $myVar, I get issues because Powershell is treating the `$_` as code, and not a string. I'm looking for a way to escape this character.

I've tried using `Regex::Escape()` but this literally replaces every special character with their "escaped version". To the point where my string loses integrity and none of my existing processing works on it (because it's content has changed). I'm looking for a way that will keep my string intact without having PS interpret the special character. So far, I've had no problems with other special characters ($, ^, *, +, ?). It's just this one edge case of `$_` that breaks my processing.

Here's an snippet of what `$myVar` could contain

```
bucket = testdata \
| search NOT CommandLine IN ("\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /c PowerShell.exe -command \"get-Hotfix *", "\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /c PowerShell.exe -command \"(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\PowerShell\\3\\PowerShellEngine -Name 'PowerShellVersion').PowerShellVersion\"", "\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /c (wmic service where 'name like \"%%*%%\"' get name, startname /format:csv)", "\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /c powershell -c \"(Get-Counter '\\Process(*)\\%% Processor Time').Countersamples | Where-Object cookedvalue -gt 0 | Sort-Object cookedvalue -Desc | Select-Object -First 10 | Format-Table -a instancename, @{Name='CPU %%';Expr={[Math]::Round($_.CookedValue)}}","\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /c powershell.exe -c \"Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_logicaldisk | Select-Object Caption, Freespace\"")\
```

The above is just a snippet, the actual variable can contain 100s of such lines.

In the above however, you can see the line `;Expr={[Math]::Round($_.CookedValue)}}`. The `$_` is where I'm having trouble.

Can someone help me find a way to not have PS interpret the content of my string literally, without morphing the actual content of the variable?

Comment: you need a backtick to escape the dollar sign inside an expandable string

Comment: Very interesting @mklement0. This issue surfaces nowhere in my processing except when I use it in a replace command like so
`$myContent = ($myContent -replace '(?<=search\s=\s).*[\s*](?s).*', $myVar)`

The idea is I extract `$myVar` from `$myContent`, do some processing to it, and replace it back. Everything works fine except the end replacement. Do you have any suggestions here to treat `$myVar` as a single-quoted string for this one command?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface:**

- In PowerShell, **`$` chars.** only have **special meaning** in [expandable (`"..."`) string ***literals***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings): they are interpreted as the start of a variable name (e.g. `$var`) or subexpression (e.g., `$(1+2)`) to *interpolate*, i.e. to replace with their value.
- In (possibly resulting-from-literals) **string *values*** stored in *variables* or *properties*, **they do *not*** (except if passed to `Invoke-Expression`, which is [best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)).

  - Inside `"..."` literals (and in `Invoke-Expression` input), escape `$` chars. with `` ` `` (the so-called *backtick*, [PowerShell's escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)) to use them verbatim.
  - Use [*verbatim* (`'...'`) string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) to prevent interpolation altogether.

---

In other words: there isn't a problem with `$_` being stored in the value of variable `$myVar` per se - PowerShell won't interpret that value unless explicitly asked to do so.

The **problem** turned out to be the **use of `$myVar` in a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation**:

> `$myContent -replace '(?<=search\s=\s).*[\s*](?s).*', $myVar`

As in the analogous parameter of the underlying [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) .NET API, **in the substitution operand** in a `-replace` operation **`$` *also* happens to have special meaning**, but that meaning is *specific to the .NET regex engine* and *unrelated to PowerShell*:

- In the substitution operand, `$`-prefixed tokens refer to *parts of what the search operand matched*; the search operand is the first RHS operand, and it is invariably interpreted as a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), such as `'f(o+)'` in the following example:

  ```
   # $1 refers to what the 1st (...) (capture group) matched.
   'foo' -replace 'f(o+)', 'g$1'  # -> 'goo'
  ```
- To use *verbatim* `$` chars. in the substitution operand, *escape* them by doubling them (`$$`)

  ```
   'foo' -replace 'f(o+)', 'g$$'  # -> 'g$'
  ```

To **escape all `$` chars. in a substitution operand *programmatically***, it is simplest to use the **`.Replace()` string method**; therefore:

```
$myContent -replace '(?<=search\s=\s).*[\s*](?s).*', $myVar.Replace('$', '$$')
```

(`$myVar -replace '\$', '$$$$'` would work too, but may be confusing.)

Note:

- In the *substitution* operand - which are themselves *not* regexes - `$` is the *only* metacharacter that requires escaping.
- In the ***search* operand**, because it is a ***regex***, many more metacharacters are recognized; while they can be `\`-escaped individually for verbatim use, the robust way to escape them programmatically is via **[`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)**.

For a concise but comprehensive overview of the `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

Comment: Your solution using .Replace inline worked, thank you :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Izy-.